# Error al importar excel a una tabla sql server atraves de asp mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, excel, oledb

Saludos tengo un programa que importa datos de un archivo excel a una tabla en sql server pero me muestra el siguiente error:

> The view 'The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched

Codigo fuente:

```
namespace Excel.Controllers public class ImportController : Controller
{


    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
    OleDbConnection Econ;



    // GET: Import
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }




    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            string filepath = "/excelfolder/" + filename;
            file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/excelfolder"), filename));
            InsertExceldata(filepath, filename);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return View(ex.Message);
        }

        return View();
    }

    private void ExcelConn(string filepath)
    {
        string constr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""", filepath);

        Econ = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    }

    private void InsertExceldata(string fileepath, string filename)
    {
        string fullpath = Server.MapPath("/excelfolder") + filename;
        ExcelConn(fullpath);
        string query = string.Format("select * from [{0}]", "Sheet1$");


        OleDbCommand Ecom = new OleDbCommand(query, Econ);
        Econ.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, Econ);
        Econ.Close();
        oda.Fill(ds);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
        objbulk.DestinationTableName = "Clientes";
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Nombre", "Nombre");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Articulo", "Articulo");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Precio", "Precio");
        con.Open();
        objbulk.WriteToServer(dt);
        con.Close();

    }
}
```

}

ACTUALIZO:

Cambie el codigo de string query a este:

```
                string query = string.Format("Select * from Clientes.xlsx");
```

Pero tira otro error:

> The view 'The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file 'Clientes'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

Comment: Y en el Excel que estás abriendo, existe una hoja llamada "Sheet1$"?

Comment: Roger te comento que si, he intentado cambiar la hoja y cambiarla en el codigo pero sigue con el mismo error

Comment: Como @RogerTorné comenta primero asegurate que la ruta es correcta para el archivo, que este se abra correctamente y el nombre de la hoja exista.

Comment: Ya he verificado la ruta y nombre y sigue  igual